# API for powerpoint presentations to flash

Tags: flash, powerpoint

How do I go about automating conversions from PowerPoint to flash?
I want a user to be able to upload a PowerPoint file into my web page and on the server I want to convert the PowerPoint to a flash movie. Is there any preferred method for doing this?
I've searched on Google and I just keep getting a lot of 3rd party software vendors selling addon software but I can't seem to find any useful guides or tutorials for doing this.

Comment: you're saying that you want to have some source code/guidance to do this for free (i.e. not pay for a 3rd party solution for this)?

Comment: correct I'm just looking for a little direction on how to do this without a 3rd party application/spltuion.  Any opensource projects or places where I could see this being done would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two (decent) solutions that I know of - the first being a little more decent than the second.

1. iSpring offers a free version of
   their PowerPoint to Flash converter called [iSpringFree](http://www.ispringfree.com/).
   It's decent. I use the Pro version
   because I also have a need to add
   e-Learning/SCORM functionality - but
   if you don't have that need, it
   should be fine. In general, it also
   one of the better converters out
   there (amongst a host of many
   pay-for PPT->SWF converters).
2. You could open your PPT/PPTX in
   [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/)'s Impress and then
   Export to Flash format.

Having server-side triggered conversion is a little more tricky - I don't know of a server-side component other than they pay-for SDK solution by iSpring that offers this. The two above are for manual conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another tool for [Powerpoint conversion into Flash](http://www.ppt2swfsdk.com/) - PPT2SWF SDK. If to check on there website they say it's convenient to use, produces a good quality conversion result, possibility of a preview. It is also SDK so you can customize it and even sell officially.